# Maven location (when installed indirectly with Netbeans/Glassfish)?

Tags: maven, netbeans, glassfish

Where is the maven home directory when you install Netbeans with Glassfish? I have searched for 'mvn' in the Program Files directory and my user directory in Windows 7 but it turns up nothing.

In the Maven settings in Netbeans for 'Maven Home' it says 'Bundled' which isn't much use to me, I need the actual path to maven.

Comment: If it's bundled you haven't installed a version can be accessed directly via command line. If you like having one just download it from maven.apache.org.

Comment: The repository is located at `c:\Users\your_username\.m2\` if that helps.

Comment: The repository has nothing to do with the installation of the command line tool.

Comment: @khmarbaise Will installing a standalone version interfere with the version already installed with netbeans? By messing up the local repository for example?

Comment: No it doesn't. What do you mean by **messing up the local repository**? If you do maven builds everything which is needed for the builds will be downloaded by Maven and installed into your local repository.

Answer (score 35):

First install maven separately (and verify it by running mvn command line) and then open netbeans and navigate to Tools -> Options -> Java -> Maven (I guess you already know that but just in case) and change the 'Maven Home' path to the directory where maven is installed.

[image]

The **Bundled** maven could generally be found at *NetBeans_install_directory*/java/maven.

Example For Mac:
/Applications/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java/maven/
Example For Windows:
C:/Program Files/Netbeans 8.2/java/maven/

Comment: What? No, this isn't the correct answer, @Ashokkumar. The question asks "Where is the Maven location _when installed indirectly with Netbeans/Glassfish_", not "How can I specify which Maven installation Netbeans uses."

Answer (score 12):

Not sure what version you downloaded back then, but with version 7.3, maven is found here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.3\java\maven\

Answer (score 3):

In Mac OS it is in

```
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.0.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java/maven/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its an old question but still there's also another way of seeing where mvn is installed on your Netbeans.

When you clean and build your project you can see in the console output the location of maven used.  See the red circle in the screenshot  `/home/<user>/netbeans-8.2/java/maven/bin/mvn`

[image]

Comment: your answer helped me, and i upvoted, but also i like your "circle" :) (i know i'm being very literal here, sorry for that!)

Answer (score 0):

**The maven bundled with NetBeans located at**

```
% NetBeans Installation Location %\java\maven
```

Eg: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven\bin