# To build this project Maven (or greater) is required

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I installed latest version of Netbeans (8.0.2) with Maven (4.27.1) installed as a plugin (so by default).

When I try to build latest version of optaplanner (6.3.0) I get exception

```
Building OptaPlanner examples 6.3.0.Final
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-plugin-versions) @ optaplanner-examples ---

--- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-java-version) @ optaplanner-examples ---

--- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-maven-version) @ optaplanner-examples ---
Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion failed with message:
To build this project Maven 3.2.3 (or greater) is required. Please install it.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
--------------------------------------------------------------

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-maven-version) on project optaplanner-examples: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

What can I do in order to build this project ?

Comment: this question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14026314/2423066

Answer (score 1):

4.27.1 can be a Netbeans Maven Plugin version, but not Maven version (there is no Maven 4 yet). You need to find out in settings what Maven is used and maybe install a new version in your system if you have Maven 2 (instead of 3) installed.

Answer (score 0):

in the setting of intellij there is a option called maven, in which you can set the maven version intellij should use.

As I recall the default ist 3.10 or so but if you have maven installed (with an other version) you can select it in the intellij settings

Comment: The question mentioned using Netbeans, not Intellij Idea.

Comment: oh sorry didnt read the whole question, because the error message sounded familiar