# Lombok not working in a Netbeans project

Tags: netbeans, lombok

I want to use Lombok in a project to use @Getter and @Setter.

I included using Maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Import is OK for Netbeans:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
```

But auto setters and getters don't work (no autocompletion / "cannot find symbol ...").

Strange thing is that for another project I have it's working fine! But I can't figure the differences.

I tested to:

- change the lombok version (even the last): for any version, the import don't work anymore
- build the project with Maven: it's OK!
- use Eclipse: it's OK! (but I am the only one to decide unfortunately)

=> so I'm sure this is a Netbeans related problem

- enable annotation processing, as I've seen in tutorials=> I don't have such option in my project properties

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: after a long time to be kept as a reference - whoever has problems with this please also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54168043/57033 which suggests to incorporate lombok as a path in maven-compiler-plugin

Answer (score 10):

In Netbeans 8.2 using Apache Maven 3.5.4 use Lombok [1.18.4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.18.4) or much older [1.16.16](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.16.16).

***In Netbeans 10.0/9.0 using [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) 3.5.4 use Lombok [1.18.4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.18.4), older versions of Lombok are [really](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1770) [buggy](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1577) when [Compile On Save](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCompileOnSave) is used in Netbeans 10.0/9.0***

I updated Lombok to a new [version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.18.4)([The newer the version the better](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok))

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <version>1.18.8</version> <!--1.18.8 for Netbeans 9/10 OR 1.16.16 for Netbeans 8 with Java 8 -->
</dependency>
```

**NB**

- **For maven-compiler-plugin, remove any annotationProcessorPaths to do
  with Lombok in the maven-compiler-plugin**
- **Remove any Lombok maven plugins**

This is not needed, as Maven and Netbeans does this out of the box. You only need the right Lombok dependency in Maven.

Comment: True, use 1.18.0 in Netbeans 9 RC1. I've added details. It also works in Netbeans 9 VC3 https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans-java/incubating-9.0-vc3

Comment: Doesn't work either :( I have cleaned target, settings file, re-imported the project ...

Comment: Thanks! It works now, I was using the bundled Maven of Netbeans 9 (3.3.9). I have switched to the latest version (3.5.4) and everything is fine now :)

Comment: Doesn't work on Netbeans 10.0. Am still wondering why the option for **"enable annotation processing"** is non-existent in _netbeans 10.0_

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa , I have never enabled "enable annotation processing" in netbeans. Make sure you [use Maven 3.5+][https://stackoverflow.com/a/14045358/338249] , with older versions the compiler plugin gives issues. Bundled in Netbeans 10 is 3.3.9

Comment: @rjdkolb This is my [`pom.xml` file](https://gist.github.com/steven7mwesigwa/f80356b8d375847a9acd5dcd7a81ae1c). May be am missing something. And am using maven 3.5.4. It throws errors [here](https://gist.github.com/steven7mwesigwa/b05c05a41a7ac65ee43829eb8a74acd5)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa Ah, there is your issue. Remove the Lombok plugin, it's not needed. updating my answer

Comment: @rjdkolb. I see. Interestingly, that fixed the problem. It now even works with the latest versions i.e lombok(v1.18.8), maven-compiler-plugin(v3.8.1), Apache maven (v3.6.1), Netbeans(v10). Thanks man.

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/project-lombok/xbgzA86pvJs

=> update version of maven-compiler-plugin was the only way to make it work

Comment: Updating to maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.0 fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

This worked with us:

- remove `<scope>provided</scope>` from the Lombok dependency
- clean and build the project
- change the Lombok version (we changed from `1.16.20` to `1.16.16`)
- clean and build the project
- restore the Lombok version and put back `<scope>provided</scope>`
- clean and build the project

Comment: WOW. Great Solution for me

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this weird workaround!

Answer (score 1):

configure the pom

```
<properties>
    <src.dir>src/main/java</src.dir>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>lombok-build</id>
        <properties>
            <src.dir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/delombok</src.dir>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.8</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${src.dir}</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.16.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>delombok</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
                        <addOutputDirectory>false</addOutputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then, specify lombok-build as the active profile for various actions (build, debug etc) under Project Properties->Actions->Activate Profiles.

At this [blog](http://brunomarinho.me/2017/05/20/maven-netbeans-lombok/) there is a github sample project and the configuration with pictures to use lastest version of maven+netbeans+lombok, that works for me.