# spring-boot-configuration-processor is not working on maven submodule project

Tags: maven, spring-boot, configuration

I have a maven multi module project with one parent and three child modules.
The application uses spring boot. In one of the child modules, I have the SpringBootApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({AppProperties.class})
public class MainSpringBootApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainSpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The App Properties are in the same module:

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "asdf")
public class AppProperties {
...
}
```

In the pom.xml of that module there is a dependency for the spring-boot-configuration-processor:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Now the problem is, when I run mvn install on the parent project, the target/classes/META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json
file within this child module is not created. When I modify the pom of that child module to directly inherit from:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

and do mvn install directly on the child module, the target/classes/META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json file is generated.

Do you have any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I explicitly added:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <annotationProcessorPaths>
        <annotationProcessorPath>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </annotationProcessorPath>
      </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

to the `plugins` section of the pom of the child module containing the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated class. Now `target/classes/META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json` is generated.

Comment: unfortunately, if we did sone, then the Lombok is not recognized

Comment: [For whoever ends up having issues with lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42257379/how-to-configure-lombok-with-maven-compiler-plugin)

Answer (score 6):

There are two options I am aware of.
First one is my favourite (especially because it configures the order of APT libraries - the order of code generation).
But based, say, on the IDE auto-discovery mechanism, the 2nd one is also a good bet.

Both ones are primarily targeting the minimum size of the final artefact (dependencies' scope), which, for me is very important.
Not to increase the deliverable/archetype size with useless  dependencies (apt libraries are needed only at compile time) is very important in the era of k8s/docker/cloud (resource efficiency).

So, without further ado, the options:

1. Use APT libraries only in maven compiler plugin configuration (nothing in dependencies).

```xml
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
               <configuration>
                   <annotationProcessorPaths>
                       <path>
                           <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                           <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                           <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                       </path>
                       <path>
                           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                           <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                           <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                       </path>
                   </annotationProcessorPaths>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
```

2. This option is useful for the case the maven-compiler-plugin is not configured in plugins/pluginsManagement (but probably by means of its properties).

```xml
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
           <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
```

***Notes:***

- For option 2, scope provided is important, because it will allow to use the APT during the compilation but won't be included in the final artefact).
- On the other hand (back to your question), in order to generate documentation in `target/classes/META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json` from the java doc, for lombok based java classes, you need these as well (@Getter and @Setter - are both needed).

```java
@Setter
@Getter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "asdf")
public class AppProperties {

   /**
    * foo - Should not be null or empty.
    */
   private Map<String, String> foo;
```

and the following maven compiler plugin configuration as property (or in the plugin configuration).

```xml
   <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
```

- After the compilation the IDE will parse the `spring-configuration-metadata.json` file and offer suggestion/quick doc/autocomplete in application.properties/application.yml.

Kr

Comment: Second option works very well with `org.mapstruct`: `<dependency> <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId> <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId> <scope>provided</scope> </dependency>`

Comment: `<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>` - is a default value, you can just skip it - without that line everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this lib "import org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONObject;", I changed to use "import org.json.JSONObject;".

I don't know exact reason but i tried and run well. You can try this solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).