# lombok @Data not generating getters and setters

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, lombok

I am using @Data annotation on my entity class.

```
 @Data public class Test {
    private String name;
    private String lName;
```

I am using the latest lombok dependency

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The class file after maven compile/package look like this

```
 package ******.models;

        public class Test {
            private String name;
            private String lName;

            public Test() {
            }
```

Any idea on this error?Using  IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE where lombok plugin is active

Comment: What JDK do you use? Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42257379/how-to-configure-lombok-with-maven-compiler-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your annotation processing in IntelliJ is off. You can turn it on by referring to the following image

[image]

Comment: No,its on and same as the above configurations