# Spring Boot Rest API Returns Empty JSON Used with Lombok

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, lombok, spring-rest

I have Spring Boot Application with Web, JPA, H2, Web, Lombok dependency.
I have entities as follows

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Getter
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer pageCount;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author;

}
```

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Getter
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String lastName;

}
```

I am getting following JSON in repose for the /books REST endpoint

```
[
    {},
    {}
]
```

If I add getters and setters to entity it works fine. How can I get the actual values in response without adding getters setters as I am using @Data annotation

Comment: You don't need Getter and Data at the same time, Data already sets up your getters. Also Entity should be used with Table(name = "table_name"
) annotation.

Comment: You shouldn't use @Data at all on JPA types since the 'toString', 'equals', and 'hashCode' need to be handled properly.   Please see my answer for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/34299054/1331935.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching a lot and looking on the answers to my question found a solution.
If I run my spring boot app using **java -jar** from cmd it works fine. But not with IDE so issue was with IDE configuration.

I am using Eclipse IDE

**Right Click on your project** -> **Properties**

Then from Properties window

**Java Compiler** -> **Annotation Processing** -> **Enable Annotation Processing**

This option should be checked then annotations gets processed. I followed https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide from Tinku's answer on this question.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First of all , In spring it is not a good approach to return the entity object directly from  a controller to be converted to json. Use the DTO approach so that you will always have a DTO object returned from the controller endpoint. This way you will have more control over the type and structure of data you want to retun from the endpoint.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174516/rest-api-dtos-or-not#36175349) about the advantages of using a DTO .

Secondly, verify that your tables follow the basic `spring jpa` naming conventions or is same as the entity class names if not please add the `@Table(name="")` annotation to specify the table name. Check that data is being populated to your entity classes.

**Remove the `@Data` annotation.**

`@Data` should not be used on JPA Entities as Entity `toString`, `equals`, and `hashCode` methods need to be authored in a very specific manner. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34299054/1331935) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it helped me to understand the standard implementations.

Comment: Are the entities retrieving data from the database ? Does you entity class have any data when being returned from the controller ? Could you share your code .

Comment: If I add the getters and setters it works fine. I checked after adding those I was getting the desired output.

Comment: You shouldn't use @Data at all on JPA types since the 'toString', 'equals', and 'hashCode' need to be handled properly. Please see my answer for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/34299054/1331935. I will update this answer.

Answer (score 1):

need to add Lombok plugin in maven or gradle file link [How to configure Lombok with maven-compiler-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42257379/how-to-configure-lombok-with-maven-compiler-plugin).
If you are  using IDE then need to install Lombok plugin link https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse check to have Lombok installed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, but neither enabling the Annotation Processing nor changing my code (e.g. remove @Data) helped me to solve this issue.

I had added this line to my `build.gradle`

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
```

But I was missing the following one to make it work:

```
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
```