# Lombok Getter/Setter are not being accessed in Netbeans 11

Tags: netbeans-8, lombok, netbeans-11

Recently I have started using Netbeans(NB) 11. Previously I used NB 8.2. I opened my NB 8.2 projects in NB 11 where I have used Lombok. I noticed that NB 11 is giving red marks where i have used Getter/Setter of Lombok. But in the compile time it is working. As we know for Objects having Lombok Getter/Setter, if we press ctrl+space we get suggestion but for NB 11, no suggestion is showing. 
How can Lombok work for NB 11?

**Update**

I have also done

"In the project properties, in the section Build – Compiling, check the 'Enable Annotation Processing in Editor' checkbox."

[image]

Comment: Are you using @Singular anywhere? This bug might be affecting you: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2093

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some configuration for Netbeans.

https://projectlombok.org/setup/netbeans

> The Netbeans editor is compatible with lombok.
>
> 1. Add lombok.jar to the project libraries.
> 2. In the project properties, in the section Build – Compiling, check the 'Enable Annotation Processing in Editor' checkbox.

Also, check [Lombok not working in a Netbeans project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36859312/lombok-not-working-in-a-netbeans-project) in case the above is not sufficient.

Comment: @BlackSwan which versions of Lombok and Maven are you using? Can you paste block that imports the Lombok dependency? Which version of the maven-compiler-plugin do you use?

Comment: yes,i have tried with the latest version of lombok 1.18. but i am not sure from which version i have started to get problem cause as you know lombok jar file dont contain version number with jar file name.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with a Maven based project

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with

- Netbean 14
- Maven based project
- JDK 16
- Spring Boot (just info)

I managed to get the lombok annotation working fine by adding below configuration in the pom.xml, working fine mean it's showing in the auto-complete feature, not showing as error with red underline, and able to be compiled normally.

First, add the dependency for lombok maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then add the annotation processor paths

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <debug>false</debug>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.24</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After that, do the `mvn clean package`

[image]